# Можно ли сделать хедер один раз, и подключать его к остальным страницам

Tags: html

Можно ли сделать хедер один раз, и подключать его к остальным страницам.

Comment: В html? Нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в html нет. Это привилегия сайтов с backend'ом. В разных языках и фреймворках это реализуется по разному.

Comment: Ne tolko s backendom.